# Creating a Contact Us <section>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a "Contact Us" `<section>` on my page but I am having trouble because I am new to rails. I want anyone to enter in their email, name, phone number, and a message and upon clicking `submit` an email would be sent to me with their name, phone number, email, and message. I would like to do this without a page reload as well. I;m not quite sure how to go about this and I have been reading posts and documentation all day but I am still having trouble putting the pieces together.

I am trying to create a form to pass the submitted data into my controller action (`HomeController`, `send_mail` action) but I am currently coming across this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"send_mail", :controller=>"home"}`

According to example 1.2 (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) It seemed to me that I can do this

HTML:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "home", action: "send_mail"}, method: "post") %>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= text_field(:name) %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= email_field(:email) %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= telephone_field(:phone) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div class="col-md-6">
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def send_mail
    name = params[:name]
    email = params[:email]
    phone = params[:phone]
    # body = params[:body]
    #UserMailer.contact_mail(name, email, body).deliver
  end
end
```

Mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: "myemail@gmail.com"

  def contact_mail(name, email, body)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @body = body

    mail(from: email, subject: "Contact Request")
  end
end
```

Comment: Check your error there partner: **No route matches**. Have you added a route that maps to this controller and action in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @BrandonBuck I have not. I did not think I needed to because I wanted this to be done on a single page. Similar to this page http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/

Comment: @Liondancer: one page or not, you still need a route.

Comment: Everything that sends a request from a client (the users browser) to your rails application (or any HTTP web server) has to have a route to ping. Rails throws this error when you don't specify a route. If you don't mind some advice, you're doing too much at once. Get your contact form working in the most simple way possible (posting and reloading the page) and then add on more functionality. You're most likely looking for the remote option of a form, [check here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: @BrandonBuck Advice is golden to me at this point haha thank you I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to expand my comment here as an answer.

The error that you're getting **No route matches {:action=>"send_mail", :controller=>"home"}** makes it pretty clear what the underlying problem is with your contact form not working. Anytime you're going to do something on the server side (like call a controller action) you need a route that maps a request to a controller and action. If you open up your `routes.rb` file and add a line like this:

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
  # ... probably some stuff

  post "contact" => "home#send_mail"
  # This line generates http://localhost:3000/contact as a valid endpoint for POST
  # (create) requests. I chose post because you're creating an email.
  # Also note the "home#send_mail" string specifying what to do with this route.
  # This is formatted as "controller#action" and is a more standard means to specify
  # the controller and action to handle a route.

  # ... probably some more stuff
end
```

When you've done your work there, your contact form should now submit the request, although with a page load.

Additionally, adding this as a route (which is required) adds a route helper to your views so instead of that bulky and name dependent hash `{action: "send_mail", controller: "home"}` with the more simple and readable `contact_path` helper. At any time in development you wish to view all valid routes, helper names and linked controller actions simply go to the root of your rails project and type `rake routes`.

And as a final note, you're wanting to make the request via AJAX (or asynchronously) to avoid reloading the page when the contact form is submitted - you're going after the `remote` option.

```
<%= form_tag contact_path, remote: true do %>
  <!-- Form contents here, as normal, rails' unobtrusive JavaScript will handle
       nabbing the forms contents and submitting them asynchronously for you. -->
<% end %>
```